# Strange visual behavior when using a Tkinter OptionMenu() widget with many choices on Macintosh (10.13.6)

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm working with a GUI where I give the user a choice of many different colormaps.

**The issue is that when the dropdown list of the `OptionMenu()` gets near the bottom of the screen, the whole box shifts down to an odd place.**

I'm not sure if this is a bug or if there is something I am doing wrong. Example code provided below, along with an image of what happens before and after the list box gets shifted down (Left vs right have 7 other widgets above vs. 8).

Note that if you're trying to reproduce the issue, your resolution may require a longer list/lower dropdown.

```
from tkinter import *

class GUI(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        Tk.__init__(self)
        self.initGUI()

    def initGUI(self):
        self.cmapchoice = StringVar()
        self.cmapchoice.set('jet')
        self.cmaps = sorted(['viridis', 'plasma', 'inferno', 'magma','binary', 
            'bone','spring', 'summer', 'autumn', 'winter', 'cool','hot','copper','Spectral', 
            'coolwarm', 'bwr', 'seismic','twilight', 'hsv', 'Paired', 'Accent', 'prism', 'ocean', 
            'terrain','brg', 'rainbow', 'jet'],key=lambda s: s.lower())
        for i in range(8): # Change this to 7 to "fix" the issue
            Label(self,text='OTHER WIDGETS').grid(row=i, column=1, sticky='WE')
        OptionMenu(self,self.cmapchoice,*self.cmaps).grid(row=9, column=1, sticky='WE')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainWindow = GUI()
    MainWindow.mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: If anyone on mac wants to reproduce the issue just add `self.geometry('+100+250')` in the `GUI` class. It might be different depending on the screen size.

Answer (score 0):

While I'm still not sure what to do about this behavior, I learned that the Combobox widget from ttk is much better anyways, since it is much more compact and doesn't take up the whole screen when opening.

Answer (score 0):

There can be a workaround to this problem, though this is not an exact fix to the problem but solves the issue. If opening the menu above the [`Menubutton`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/menubutton.htm) *(OptionMenu widget without any dropdown menu)* then it will never shift to the bottom of the screen.

The direction of the dropdown menu can be set with [`direction`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/menubutton.htm#Tkinter.Menubutton.config-method) argument of `Menubutton`. Like so...

```py
op = OptionMenu(...)
op['direction'] = 'above'
```

*Complete example*

```py
from tkinter import *

class GUI(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        Tk.__init__(self)
        self.initGUI()

    def initGUI(self):
        self.cmapchoice = StringVar()
        self.cmapchoice.set('jet')
        self.cmaps = sorted(['viridis', 'plasma', 'inferno', 'magma','binary', 
            'bone','spring', 'summer', 'autumn', 'winter', 'cool','hot','copper','Spectral', 
            'coolwarm', 'bwr', 'seismic','twilight', 'hsv', 'Paired', 'Accent', 'prism', 'ocean', 
            'terrain','brg', 'rainbow', 'jet'],key=lambda s: s.lower())
        for i in range(8): # Change this to 7 to "fix" the issue
            Label(self,text='OTHER WIDGETS').grid(row=i, column=1, sticky='WE')
        op = OptionMenu(self, self.cmapchoice, *self.cmaps)
        op.grid(row=9, column=1, sticky='WE')
        op['direction'] = 'above'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainWindow = GUI()
    MainWindow.mainloop()
```